# error at the "return" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a table valued function in sql server and facing an error at the "return statement"
All the statements in the code are correct only, but i don't know why this error

my error is

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.
```

my sql function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[WEEKLY_REPORT](@START_DATE DATETIME, @END_DATE DATETIME,@PRACTISE NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @WEEKLY_REPORT_DETAILS_INFORMATION TABLE
(
RESOURCE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
DAY1 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY2 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY3 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY4 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY5 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY6 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY7 DECIMAL(5,2),
UTILIZATION INT
)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @RESOURCE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @DAY1 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY2 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY3 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY4 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY5 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY6 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @DAY7 DECIMAL(5,2),
    @UTILIZATION INT,
    @LAST_DAY1 INT,
@MONTH NVARCHAR(MAX),
@START_DAY INT,
@END_DAY INT,
@COUNT INT,
@COUNT_TEST INT,
@QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);
BEGIN
    SET @MONTH = DATENAME(MONTH,@START_DATE)
    SET @START_DAY = DATENAME(DAY,@START_DATE)
    SET @END_DAY = DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE)
    SET @COUNT = @END_DAY -@START_DAY + 1
--  SET @QUERY='SELECT A.NAME, '

--SET @QUERY = ' INSERT INTO @WEEKLY_REPORT_DETAILS_INFORMATION(RESOURCE_NAME,DAY1,DAY2,DAY3,
--              DAY4,DAY5,DAY6,DAY7,UTILIZATION) SELECT A.NAME,'
CREATE TABLE TEMP(RESOURCE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), DAY1 DECIMAL(5,2),
    DAY2 DECIMAL(5,2),
    DAY3 DECIMAL(5,2),
    DAY4 DECIMAL(5,2),
    DAY5 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY6 DECIMAL(5,2),
DAY7 DECIMAL(5,2))

SET @QUERY = ' INSERT INTO #TEMP(RESOURCE_NAME,DAY1,DAY2,DAY3,DAY4,DAY5,DAY6,DAY7)' +
             ' SELECT A.NAME,'
    SET @COUNT_TEST = 1
WHILE @COUNT_TEST <= @COUNT
BEGIN
    IF(DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE)=DATEPART(MONTH,@END_DATE))
    BEGIN
        IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@START_DAY)
        SET @START_DAY = @START_DAY + 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@START_DAY) + ', ' 
        SET @START_DAY = @START_DAY + 1
    END
    SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1    
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    IF( DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 1 OR DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 3 OR
        DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 5 OR DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 7 OR
        DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 8 OR DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 10 OR
        DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 12 )
    BEGIN   
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@START_DATE)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <= 31 )
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1 
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1  
        END
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE) - (DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE)-1)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <=  DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE))
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1      
        END
    END
    ELSE 
    IF( DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 4 OR DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 6 OR
             DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 9 OR DATEPART(MONTH,@START_DATE) = 11 )
    BEGIN       
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@START_DATE)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <= 30 )
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)       
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1      
        END
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE) - (DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE)-1)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <=  DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE))
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1      
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@START_DATE)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <= 28 )
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1   
        END
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE) - (DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE)-1)
        WHILE (@LAST_DAY1 <=  DATENAME(DAY,@END_DATE))
        BEGIN
            IF(@COUNT_TEST =@COUNT)
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'B.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1)
            ELSE
                SET @QUERY=@QUERY + 'C.D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR ,@LAST_DAY1) + ', '
        SET @COUNT_TEST =@COUNT_TEST + 1
        SET @LAST_DAY1 = @LAST_DAY1 +1   
        END
    END
END 
END

IF(DATENAME(MONTH,@START_DATE)=DATENAME(MONTH,@END_DATE))
BEGIN
    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' FROM EMPLOYEE A JOIN CP_DETAILS B' +
                ' ON A.ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID WHERE B.MONTH_USED = ' + '''' + @MONTH + '''' +
                ' AND B.YEAR_USED = ' + DATENAME(YEAR,@START_DATE) + 
                ' AND B.PRACTISE=' + '''' + @PRACTISE + ''''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ' FROM EMPLOYEE A JOIN CP_DETAILS B' +
                ' ON A.ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID JOIN CP_DETAILS C ON A.ID=C.EMPLOYEE_ID' +
                ' WHERE B.MONTH_USED = ' + '''' + DATENAME        (MONTH,@START_DATE) + '''' +
                ' AND B.YEAR_USED = ' + DATENAME(YEAR,@START_DATE) + 
                ' AND B.PRACTISE=' + '''' + @PRACTISE + '''' + 
                ' AND C.MONTH_USED=' + '''' + DATENAME(MONTH,@END_DATE) + ''''
END

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY

DECLARE CP_DETAILS CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM TEMP

OPEN CP_DETAILS
FETCH NEXT FROM CP_DETAILS INTO @RESOURCE_NAME,@DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS =0)
BEGIN
    SET @UTILIZATION = dbo.UTILIZATION(@START_DATE,@END_DATE,@DAY1,
                                    @DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7)
    INSERT INTO @WEEKLY_REPORT_DETAILS_INFORMATION VALUES(@RESOURCE_NAME,
                @DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7,@UTILIZATION)

    FETCH NEXT FROM CP_DETAILS INTO @RESOURCE_NAME,@DAY1,@DAY2,@DAY3,@DAY4,@DAY5,@DAY6,@DAY7
END
CLOSE CP_DETAILS
DEALLOCATE CP_DETAILS
DROP TEMP
RETURN ---error here
END
END
```

Comment: Don't know why it tells you that the error is on `RETURN`, but this is not valid on a function: `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY`

Comment: Change "DROP TEMP" immediately preceding the "RETURN" to "DROP TABLE TEMP"

Answer (score 0):

Lamak is right, you can't use `EXEC` or `SP_EXECUTESQL` or anything like that inside a function.

Maybe you can re-write your function into a stored procedure ?

About the syntax error, shouldn't you write `DROP TABLE TEMP` instead of `DROP TEMP` ?

Comment: Agreed that this should be a stored procedure, rather than a function.  Also, `RETURN` should specify a value, e.g., `RETURN 0`.